# Why can't I save() to this Parse.Object?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

With the following code, I'm able to successfully create a Parse.Object, and view it in the databrowser:

```
// This code executes correctly:
var UPrefs = Parse.Object.extend("uPrefs");
var uPrefs = new UPrefs();
uPrefs.setACL(new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current()));
uPrefs.save();
```

After the promise has been fulfilled, the current user can no longer update the object:

```
// But then this code throws a 403 error
uPrefs.save();
```

Here are the error details:

```
code: 119
"This user is not allowed to perform the update operation on uPrefs. You can
change this setting in the Data Browser."
```

Even though the data browser shows the ACL for the row set (w/ both read & write privileges) to the user who created it, and is then trying to update it.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks if you can help!

Comment: Perhaps this will help https://parse.com/questions/class-level-permissions

Comment: Thanks, @WandMaker -- this solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With thanks to WandMaker's comments for leading me in the right direction:

To solve this I needed to:
   - add a `user` column to the `uPrefs` Parse.Object model.
   - add a pointer to the `user` column in the class level permissions, and set that to have read/create/write/update/destroy permissions.

Once that's done, the following code works:

```
var UPrefs = Parse.Object.extend("uPrefs");
var uPrefs = new UPrefs();
uPrefs.set("user", Parse.User.current());
uPrefs.setACL(new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current()));
uPrefs.save();
```

And then all future `save()` calls work as well.

Comment: Check your answer as you answered it.